# What is meant by img.at<uchar>(i,j)?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

Its kind a basic question.  I don't know what this structure.

```
img.at<uchar>(i,j)
```

is meant to be? I try to find the definition of **`at`**, but can't understand it. and what this  syntax means?

```
<uchar>
```

Similarly, what is meant by

```
img.at<cv::Vec3b>(row,col)[channel]
```

Yes, `Mat` is matrix class to manipulate matrix data. I understand the behavior of those above lines but can't understand theory behind them?

What does this syntax mean?

```
img.at<cv::Vec3b>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`at` is an overloaded C++ template function of the class `cv::Mat`.

The `< >` is the syntax for invoking a C++ template.

```
img.at<uchar>(i,j)
```

The above line means, we are accessing the pixel `(i,j)` and specifying its data type to be `unsigned char`.

In simple English, fetch 1 pixel from index `(i, j)` i.e. row number **i** and column number **j**.

```
img.at<cv::Vec3b>
```

The above is used for a 3 channel image. Same as the first one, but fetching the pixel values of all the three channels. The value returned is a `Vec3b` structure containing 3 values, one for each channel.

Comment: For completeness, note that (i,j) refers to (row,column), or in cartesian coordinates: (y,x). This is the math/matrix notation, not the typical image processing notation which usually uses (x,y) - or (column, row).